# Visual studio and Features View of IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have windows xp and would like to use the Feature View of IIS to modify my web.config file. How do i find that application in windows or visual studio 2010..

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows Server 2008 and IIS7, you can install the IIS 7 Manager onto your XP machine to remotely manage the IIS role. See http://www.iis.net/download/iismanager

Comment: What is windows server 2008? and no, i dont think that i have iis7, but iis5.. :( ... screw micorsoft

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd Screw Microsoft? Really? Why not just upgrade your Windows installation? That's typically how products work: New/better versions cost money so they can afford to make new/better versions.

Comment: So you're running IIS on your local XP machine then?

Answer (score 1):

That's reserved for IIS 7.0+. You'd have to upgrade your OS to Vista or 7. There may be 3rd party utilities that mimic that functionality though.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't know of any because I don't need one, I said there may be one. You'd have to find it for yourself.